# LIKE in Elasticsearch for large texts

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I'm trying to simulate the `LIKE` operation from SQL in Elastic.

Base Records:

```
1. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
2. The thequick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
3. The quick and brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
4. The quick brownnow fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Search SQL: `LIKE '%quick brown%'`

Results: 1, 2 and 3

And very simply I'm trying to do this in Elasticsearch 6.

So far I'm able to apply a Regex or Wildcard to a Keyword field and make this work.

However, one of my properties has a **lot of text and can't be indexed as a Keyword** - It exceeds max number of bytes.

Any pointers would be welcome! :)

Comment: What seems you want is a normal "match" query with the "and" operator. But you would have trouble with that `thequick` term in the second result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the best way to achieve this is by using Span Queries.
SpanNear and multiple wildcard queries.
I'll chuck in an example if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of mapping the field as "Text" which will enable a inverted indexes on the analyzed terms. This will support full-text search on this field. Since they are not considered as a keyword, there is no impact on the memory used.

More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html